# What's the best way to temporarily alias a mutable reference?

Tags: rust, reference, mutability

I'm trying to modify one of two arrays (which are behind mutable borrows) based on some condition. The best way to do this would be to create a temporary alias to the mutable borrow as in the following (not compiling) code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = [1;5];
    let mut y = [1;5];
    
    modify_arrays(&mut x, &mut y);
}

fn modify_arrays<'a>(arr1: &'a mut [u8], arr2: &'a mut [u8]) {
    if arr1.len() == arr2.len() {
        for i in 0 .. arr1.len() {
            let array_to_change = if i % 2 == 0 {
                arr1
            } else {
                arr2
            };
            
            array_to_change[0] += 1; // example computation on array_to_change
        }
    }
}
```

The `&mut` value in `arr1` & `arr2` is moved to `array_to_change` because `&mut` values don't implement the `Copy` trait. So I thought, use references, `&arr1` and `&arr2`. However, I then can't index into `arr1` and `arr2`, even though they are references to mutable references. So that leads to the following code which I don't like for two reasons.

1. `array_to_change` is `&mut &mut` even though it is only meant to represent one level of indirection, a reference to an array.
2. `arr1` and `arr2` are declared mutable even though I have no intention of ever mutating them.

```
fn modify_arrays<'a>(mut arr1: &'a mut [u8], mut arr2: &'a mut [u8]) {
    if arr1.len() == arr2.len() {
        for i in 0 .. arr1.len() {
            let array_to_change = if i % 2 == 0 {
                &mut arr1
            } else {
                &mut arr2
            };
            
            array_to_change[0] += 1; // example computation on array_to_change
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `&mut *arr` will re-borrow:

```
fn modify_arrays<'a>(arr1: &'a mut [u8], arr2: &'a mut [u8]) {
    if arr1.len() == arr2.len() {
        for i in 0 .. arr1.len() {
            let array_to_change = if i % 2 == 0 {
                &mut *arr1
            } else {
                &mut *arr2
            };
            
            array_to_change[0] += 1;// example computation on array_to_change...
        }
    }
}
```

See it on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85d6e7bc77397bed385d57e432832f31).